# How to set formControl value dynamically in formGroup using angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-applications

```ts
BuildCustomFields(formControl, formControlValue): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({      
      formControl: new FormControl(formControlValue),
    })
  }
```

I need to add `formControl` Value from parameter which I pass in `BuildCustomFields()` method. How can pass the value of `formControl` dynamically?

It always takes this text "formControl" as key instead of using value which I am passing to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want formControl to be your dynamic key, you need to pass reference it within `[]` otherwise you get the value of it

```
BuildCustomFields(formControl, formControlValue): FormGroup {
debugger
return this.fb.group({
  
 [formControl]: new FormControl(formControlValue),
})
```

Comment: Thanks @Salmin Skenderovic

Its working but when I give dynamic key it says

"Component.html:715 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'customFieldArray -> 0 -> Matter Value'"
When I give static value it works fine. Can you please tell me why it is throwing this error?

Comment: I have updated my question can you please have a look at html code I am giving formControlName with interpolation when I give formControl in BuildCustomFields() with static way it works fine but in dynamic way its giving this error.